# Pandas Dataframe - rename columns based on the dataframe name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, rename

I want to write a function that updates the column names of a df based on the name of the df.

I have a number of dfs with identical columns.  I need eventually to merge these dfs into one df .  To identify where the data has originally come from once merged I want to update the column names by appending an identifier to the column name in each separate df first

I have tried using a dictionary (dict) within the function to update the columns but have been unable to get this to work

I have attempted the following function:

```
def update_col(input):

    dict = {'df1': 'A'
            ,'df2': 'B'
            }
    input.rename(columns= {'Col1':'Col1-' + dict[input]
                            ,'Col2':'Col2-' + dict[input]
                            },inplace= True)
```

My test df are

df1:

```
Col1  Col2
foo   bah
foo   bah
```

df2:

```
Col1  Col2
foo   bah
foo   bah
```

Running the function as follows I wish to get:

```
update_col(df1)
```

df1:

```
Col1-A  Col2-A
foo     bah
foo     bah
```

Comment: It is not a must.  I am trying to find the most efficient/consistent way to update the columns over multiple dataframes without manually typing out each individual edit.  I am a novice and open to any suggestions as the best way to proceed.  The key is to be able to identify where the columns came from once I merge the dfs as each df represents data from a different date.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better way would be:

```
mydict = {'df1': 'A'
        ,'df2': 'B'
        }

d={'df'+str(e+1):i for e,i in enumerate([df1,df2])} #create a dict of dfs
```

---

```
final_d={k:v.add_suffix('-'+v1) for k,v in d.items() for k1,v1 in mydict.items() if k==k1}
print(final_d)
```

---

```
{'df1':   Col1-A Col2-A
0    foo    bah
1    foo    bah, 'df2':   Col1-B Col2-B
0    foo    bah
1    foo    bah}
```

you can then access the dfs as `final_d['df1']` etc.

**Note:** Please dont use `dict` as a dictionary name as it is a builtin python function

Comment: Thanks anky_91, this is great.  Will be more careful with my dictionary names in examples in future!